# convert a btye into Uint32 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does the values of `caldata` are the same after the exxcution of function of `decipher`?
I would like to take an array of bytes and convert it into Uint32.

```js
var ROUNDS = 64;
var DELTA = 0x9E3779B9;

//var seed=new Uint32Array ([0x152486F0]);
var seed = new Uint8Array([0x15, 0x24, 0x86, 0xF0]);
var u32 = seed.buffer.slice(0);
var caldata = new Uint32Array(u32)[0];
console.log("pre caldata!", caldata);
var key = [0x12345678, 0x87654321, 0xAAAAAAAA, 0xBBBBBBBB];
decipher(caldata, key);

function decipher(v, k) {
  var y = v[0];
  var sum = (DELTA * ROUNDS) >>> 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++) {
    y -= (((y << 4) >>> 0 ^ (y >>> 5)) + y) ^ (sum + k[(sum >> 11) & 3]);

    sum = (sum - DELTA) >>> 0;

  }
  v[0] = y;

}

console.log("caldata!", caldata);

console.log("Seed", seed);
```

I usually code C language and am new to javascript

Comment: your variables are not passed by reference I think

Comment: you start by `var caldata = new Uint32Array(u32)[0]` ... then pass `caldata` to the function, then read `v[0]` ... but `caldata` does not have a `[0]` property ... because it's a number

Comment: try `var caldata = new Uint32Array(u32)` instead, and `console.log(caldata[0])`

Comment: if you are excepting -12124539068 as the after caldata I figured it out

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X how can `-12124539068` be an *unsigned int 32*?

Comment: my bad it's 760362820 now

Answer (score 1):

Jaromanda X is right v parameter in your function decipher is a number which cannot be indexed into in javascript

also

in javascript primitive data types such as **numbers, strings, and booleans** are passed by **value**, while **objects and arrays** are passed by **reference**

also there is no unsigned 32 bit integer primitive type its just "number" but there is a workaround storing it in Uint32Array and **not pulling it out of the array**:

```
var ROUNDS = 64;
var DELTA = 0x9E3779B9;

var seed = new Uint8Array([0x15, 0x24, 0x86, 0xF0]);
console.log("pre Seed", seed);
var u32 = seed.buffer;
var caldata = new Uint32Array(u32);
console.log("pre caldata!", caldata[0]);
var key = [0x12345678, 0x87654321, 0xAAAAAAAA, 0xBBBBBBBB];
decipher(caldata, key);

function decipher(v, k) {
    var sum = (DELTA * ROUNDS) >>> 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++) {
        v[0] -= (((v[0] << 4) >>> 0 ^ (v[0] >>> 5)) + v[0]) ^ (sum + k[(sum >> 11) & 3]);
        sum = (sum - DELTA) >>> 0;
    }
}

console.log("caldata!", caldata[0]);
console.log("Seed", seed);
```

which outputs as:

```
pre Seed Uint8Array(4) [ 21, 36, 134, 240 ]
pre caldata! 4035322901
caldata! 760362820
Seed Uint8Array(4) [ 68, 55, 82, 45 ]
```

to reverse endianness of a U32 number you could do:

```
num = 760362820
u32arr = new Uint32Array([num])
u8arr = new Uint8Array(u32arr.buffer)
reversedU32Array = new Uint32Array(u8arr.reverse().buffer)
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I flip the endianness, so the outcome is 346164783.

Comment: big endian notation of 760362820 is 1144476205 as uint32 I am adding it to the answer

Comment: Trouble is, I think OP expects the answer to be `346164783` which would be `789488148` reversed

Comment: @JaromandaX correct, any idea I can reverse the order. thank you Jaromanda

Comment: @JOSEPH129009 there is code added to reverse the bytes, but, as stated, that doesn't help if your algorithm is incorrect - what cypher is this?

Comment: @JaromandaX I modified the XTEA to 4 btye long because my bootloader UI does not accept more than 5 bytes.

Comment: @JOSEPH129009 - I think the issue is that the encryption (which you haven't shown) doesn't decrypt using this mangled XTEA - I take it you wrote the encryption code as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX I do not have encryption code, this works as a security method. I will generate a seed and then process through this mangled XTEA

Comment: Oh, right, I misunderstood the fact that you wanted a particular value that had no relationship to the value the code gives (not even endianness)